# Lock macOS on close/sleep, but not on screensaver

Tags: macos, sleep, macbook, screensaver

Is there a way to automatically lock my Macbook when I close its lid, but not when my screensaver starts? The reason I'm posting this question is because I really enjoy my screensaver, and don't want to have to unlock my Macbook immediately after it starts, but would also like to ensure my Macbook *does* lock when I close the lid.

Comment: I'm not certain about modern macOS, but you used to be able to use 'pmset' in the terminal to dictate the lidsleep behavior... see https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2432921?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find anything for lidsleep in `pmset`, only actions for a lidwake... But cool to learn about the utility.